# Chrome Extensions Save

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, save

I am developing a chrome extension that sets a homepage. The user can add sites to his or her dashboards and add favorite sites. How can you store this data so the next time the user opens a new tab, their information is still saved? I understand you can use a chrome API and JSON but I have almost no experience with those frameworks. Can anyone show me an example of how to do that? And most importantly save any uploaded backgrounds.

Comment: Use `chrome.storage` or `localStorage`. It's a built-in feature, not a framework. There are tons of examples that you can easily find in a few seconds/minutes.

Comment: Show me were please....

Answer (score 0):

you can store and retrieve data using chrome.storage APIs.
refer this: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: All I have to do is put that line of JSON and it'll save? Sorry, I only now frontend and have no idea how JSON or api work.

Comment: You can use the `chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
          console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
        });` function to save data to chrome storage. it stores data with a key. You can later retrieve the data using the key with this API `chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
          console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
        });`.

Comment: oh. sorry, i think you misinterpret the term API. Chrome extension APIs have many pre-defined functions. We only needs to use that. I think in your case when a user adds a new site, you need to store the data inside chrome storage by using the set method. you need to provide a key to identify it. then the data will be stored on the chrome browsers storage space. Next time when the user opens a new tab, you need to fetch the value from the storage space using the get function with the key. You dont need any end point. Chrome storage APIs stores data inside the chrome browser itself.